# How to perform the instantiation of UISearchBar properly from a nested VC

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I have the firstVC as 'homeController' which has an instance of UISearchBar and implements its delegate (UISearchBarDelegate), and doing this will instantiate the secondVC which is 'searchController' and has its delegate on another instance of UISearchBar as well, I need to fix that redundancy. I am using the homeController UISearchBarDelegate just because it let me instantiate the 'searchController'.

## 1: I'm using the method for the instantiation searchBarShouldBeginEditing on 'homeController' and perhaps it is wrong because the first second loads the color properly and then it changes to black.

## 2: searchBarTextDidBeginEditing loop itself. (from the color that I want to again the color that I want). -(infinite loop)

I can only use one at the time or searchBarShouldBeginEditing or searchBarTextDidBeginEditing. I would like to use the behavior of searchBarTextDidBeginEditing, but it reloads like crazy. Or the first second of searchBarShouldBeginEditing and know where does the application is in the state of that black screen because definitely, it is not the default color that I set, because it changes the color that I want on the first second and on the second second it is black.  By the way, The application is not using the UISearchBar from the 'searchController', it is using the UISearchBar from 'homeController'. What is recommended?

Just right there I got two points.

## 1: Should I keep separated the logic as I am doing or should I mix it?

## 1.1: home and search have different cells, that's why I don't mix them. How can I use the instance of UISearchBar on 'searchController'?

## 2: If I keep it separated, should I use the UISearchBar from the 'searchController' or delete that instance and just use 'homeController'?

## how to implement or instantiate properly the UISearchBar with the current scenario?

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        handleShowSearchVC()
        return false
    }
    
    @objc func handleShowSearchVC() {
        let modalUserSearchController = UserSearchController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        modalUserSearchController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
navigationController?.pushViewController(modalUserSearchController, animated: true)
    }
    
    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        handleShowSearchVC()
    }
```

Comment: I believe there should only be one search bar, in the main view controller that displays your searchable content. This typically acts as the `UISearchResultsUpdating` delegate as well, and filters the content to be displayed in the search results controller. The search results controller is a separate controller you provide when you create the `UISearchController`. There is [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/displaying_searchable_content_by_using_a_search_controller) from Apple that might help to illustrate the process for you.

Comment: Just to clarify, the search bar should come from the `UISearchController` object you create. The `searchController` is typically assigned to the `navigationItem.searchController` property of your navigation bar (assuming iOS 11.0 and up). This will add the search bar into the navigation bar for you.

Comment: @DennisW. You really are a gentleman! I just understood what you said and btw! thank you very much for the sample code. I'll start the implementation now. I'll keep you posted. Blessings.